# iPhone Simulator - Black Screen

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, hackintosh

I successfully run basic iOS applications on my Hackintosh OS X Yosemite 10.10.1. But when i try to run any iOS app using a WebView, the simulator gets very slow, then shows a black screen and quits the app.

My PC overview:

- **Processor** 2.2 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
- **Memory** 2.00 GB 800 MHz DDR2 SDRAM
- **Graphics** Asus GeForce 8600 GT 512 MB

iPhone is pretty expensive for me. Do i have to look for real one to debug apps fine?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: too many factors there are: 2gb is extremely low amount of memory for OS X itself and especially for Xcode development. plus hackintosh... are you sure you have all kext related to video configured properly?

Comment: @heximal i did not check kexts but i can watch movies (with no sound)... Could you please suggest me how much RAM should i use?

Comment: Apple engineers recommends 8Gb minimum for comfortable Xcode development

Comment: @heximal so i'll add RAM first. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS development on Hackintosh u need at least 4Gb RAM.